# Transforming JSON data to match new Java model

Tags: java, json, jackson

My java application makes use of complex object graphs that are jackson annotated and serialized to json in their entirety for client side use. Recently I had to change one of the objects in the domain model such that instead of having two children of type `X` it will instead contain a `Set<X>`. This changed object is referenced by several types of objects in the model.

The problem now is that I have a large quantity of test data in json form for running my unit tests that I need to convert to this new object model. My first thought for updating the json files was to use the old version java object model to deserialize the json data, create new objects using the new version object model, hydrate the new objects from the old objects and then finally serialize the new objects back to json. I realized though that the process of programmatically creating matching object graphs and then hydrating those object graphs could be just as tedious as fixing the json by hand since the object graphs are relatively deep and its not a simple clone.

I'm wondering how I can get around fixing these json files entirely by hand? I'm open to any suggestions even non-java based json transformation or parsing tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility, if Objects in question are closely-enough related, structurally, is to just read using one setting of data-binding, write using another.

For example: if using Jackson, you could consider implementing custom set and get methods; so that setters could exist for child types; but getter only for `Set` value. Something like:

```
public class POJO {
   private X a, b;

public void setA(X value) { a = value; }
   public void setB(X value) { b = value; }

public X[] getValues() {
     return new X[] { a, b };
   }
```

would, just as an example, read structure where `POJO` would have two Object-valued properties, "a" and "b", but write structure that has one property "values", with JSON array of 2 Objects.
This is just an example of the basic idea that reading in (deserialization) and serialization (writing out) need not be symmetric or identical.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was looking for! Guess I got stuck thinking about the problem in a certain way and didn't think of making the deserialization/serialization asymmetrical. Worked great with minimal coding on my part.

Comment: @Tom good -- yeah there are many possible ways, so sometimes different perspective helps a lot